# Java how to print two different values from one array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am striving to print two different values from one array of stored models of computers. At the moment my program print first computer from the index but I cannot get how to print just one of particular model.
This is a fragment of my Main class

```
ComputerList list = new ComputerList();
Coputer item;
String model;
switch (option) 
{
    case 'M':
       model = Console.askString("Enter model?: ");
   item = list.findModel(model);
if (item == null)
   System.out.println("Cannot find " + model);
else
   item.print("Computer details..." + model);
```

... and this is my  ComputerList class

```
ArrayList<Laptop> laptops;
private ArrayList<String> models;   
    public SerialList()
{
laptops = new ArrayList<Laptop>();
models = new ArrayList<String>();
}

public void add(Computer anComputer)
{
laptops.add(anComputer);
models.add(anComputer.getModel());
}

public void print()
{

    int nItems = computer.size();
    for (int i=0; i<nItems; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(computers.get(i));

}

public Computer findModel(String aModel)
{
    int index = models.indexOf(aModel);
    if (index == -1)
        return null;
    else
        return computers.get(index);
}
```

}

I really struggling resolve this matter  for few days but most of tutorials are based on numbers, values etc. 
I will be very grateful  of any help to this matter. 
Regards

Comment: You're missing a closing brace `}` of the `for` loop in the `print` method.

Comment: i realy don't understand what you are trying to do , could you please be more specific.

Comment: My current application add models of computers to the array but I would like to add user possibility to find available models just by giving model for example if user choose Linux then all computer based on Linux system will be printed. I still don't know how to add this functionality to my app.

Comment: how is this not a real question? it is rather clear what piotre is asking for. and it looks like he has been chased off the site.

Answer (score 1):

You need a list iteration through your `ComputerList`.

```
ComputerList list = new ComputerList();

for (ComputerList currentComputer: list) {
     currentComputer.print();
}
```

Just memorize the format. Also, I would use a `HashMap` or a different collection for that one  to one String -> Laptop correspondence.

Answer (score 1):

When you print an object you get the identifier @222222 etc...

You have to print attributes.
System.out.println(computer.getName + computer.getID);